# Excel VSTO ADD-IN Showing Images from Image File

Tags: excel, mvvm, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I have followed this tutorial on YouTube:[https://www.youtube.com/watch?[Build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?%5BBuild) a modern UI for an Excel VSTO Add-in using WPF / MVVM][1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AuromPv99c&t=5006s)v=5AuromPv99c&t=5006s AND can get everthing to work no problem with no errors until I try and add my own images in an Image file. The image files show up in design time until I run the program and I get a blank as far as images are concerned. I'm on my third round of this tut and still end up with an image problem.

Things I've tried: change image file to .png .jpg .ico (fail) change the build action of the Resouce file (fail) chage the file name in the xaml and have noticed if this is a clue that if I put a '/' at the beginning of the  the image shows in designer but when removed the image does'nt appear! Then When set from the image box an image is then placed into my control file? but still no image at run time! The app is not image intensive but requires a few. I've noticed as well when trying to put a Icon in Icon and Manifest the images are there in the file but it's though the program refuses to recognise my Image file, am I referenceing wrong?

Comment: What is your code? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you set an image at design time, the corresponding code is generated to get such images behind the scene by the designer. So, you may take a look at the generated code and set a breakpoint to debug it at runtime to understand why images are not displayed.